# PHP session for domain and sub domains

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

This is my code for initiating session in PHP based webapp

```
session_set_cookie_params(24*60*60, "/", ".exdomain.com");
session_start();
```

What I want is that same session to persist among all the sub domains say:

```
www.exdomain.com 
ajax.exdomain.com
```

Here the sub-domain

> ajax.exdomain.com

is used to serve users's ajax request now what is happening, user when login through www.exdomain.com
a new PHPSESSID="91252ec9310ae1c80f44c7e885cf7dfe" is created from firebug the PHPSESSID cookie is set as follows:

> PHPSESSID=91252ec9310ae1c80f44c7e885cf7dfe | .exdomain.com | 41 B | / | 29 August 2013 03:02:09 AM

now when request is made through ajax sub domain i.e. ajax.exdomain.com, a new session is being  created for this request, infact for each ajax request a new PHPSESSID is being created.
How to prevent the formation of new session for ajax request.

Comment: Did you configure the same `session_set_cookie_params()` for both subdomains?  In other words does the `ajax.exdomain.com` know to also use `.exdomain.com` as the domain for session cookie?

Comment: both use same file/function for login verification/session managment.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489426/unable-to-create-session-in-php-on-ajax-call) it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the session domain, either in .htaccess or php.ini

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".exdomain.com"
```