# Unable to create session in php on AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-cookies

I have a example.com/login.php file on root domain with this code

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_name('lusession');
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
$_SESSION['useremail'] = $_GET['useremail'];
$_SESSION['password'] =  $_GET['password'];
```

This file is provided with credentials and it then creates login session. It is called from main domain and subdomains by AJAX.

The problem is it doesnot creat session when called through AJAX, but when opened directly in browser as querystring it creates cross domain session as expected.

Other pages which call it through AJAX have following code in them at start:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_name('lusession');
session_start();
```

If I add following code in login.php it shows in AJAX response that session is created. But that session is not available on pages on same domain and on other subdomains.

```
echo 'session created for'.$_SESSION['name'];
```

Inspecting resource shows AJAX call creates session cookie with name 'lusession' as it should.

Comment: [`session.cookie_httponly`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly) (or: the 5th parameter of `session_set_cookie_params()` if you will).

Comment: I am exploring it; if you write it like an answer, as if it helped I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'll add it as a real answer. If it helps, could you perhaps alter your question to "cannot create PHP session with javascript"? More easily discoverable for the next one that runs into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well figured it out.

Actualy AJAX calls only send Cookies if the url you're calling is on the same domain as your calling script. Subdomains are considered seperate domains. Though this code creates cross subdomain sessions but AJAX involved is culprit.

As in this case I am trying to call a url from domain.com while my calling script is on sub.domain.com (In other words: I made a Cross Domain Call in which case the browser didn't sent any cookies to protect privacy).

The solution that worked for me is I put login.php file on every subdomain for calls from that subdomain. This way sessions were created, and once a session is created on one subdomain it is available on all subdomains as wanted.

Comment: AH, nice to know you found the solution

Answer (score 2):

Access to the session cookie by scripting languages is controlled with the [`session.cookie_httponly`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly) configuration setting. Or you can use the 5th parameter of `session_set_cookie_params()` if you prefer this.

Comment: Out of luck with this point, the file is working perfectly if called directly in browser. Then why is it not creating sessions on AJAX call

Comment: Does it return the cookie on the ajax call if you watch your debugger?

Comment: Yes it creates session cookie **'lusession'**

Comment: And from what domains are you working, what is the normal domain, what is the other domain?

Comment: Hm. Can you show met the exact Set-Cookie header you receive on that Ajax request?

Comment: Thanks for bearing, cookie is inspect-able on site. Can't figure out where the problem is. Question has all the essential details further links are also addend in comment below. Waiting for anybody to spot issue to accept answer